# How to create a husky "hook" precommit that check if there is any console.log() in the files

Tags: githooks, husky

I can't get the right way to create a hook for husky that prevents the debug lines in my code before a commit.

I've been reading the docs, and a some questions about the same topic, but neither of them could help me.

I want to use Husky to prevent the debug lines in my code, I'm using eslint and prettier as well, but neither of them with my current rules check if there is any debug line in the code, and I want to they stay this way, since I only want to be prevented in the precommits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-console/) in **tslint.json** file

```
"no-console": [
        true,
        "log"
    ],
```

and then add lint check in husky hook

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "ng lint",
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use .eslintrc.js file.
You can add next rule:

```
{...
  rules: {
  "no-console": "error"
  ...
  }
}
```

And then you can use in your package.json

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts}": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "pretty-quick --staged"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If add 'no-console' rule. It will block all console.log in development too.

The task:  how to create hook for pre-commit stage only.